# Simple question involving the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma

Tags: fourier-analysis

If i assume the sentence:

$$ \text{If} \  f \in L^{1}(0,1) \ \text{then} \  \displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \sin (nx) \ dx = 0  \  (n \in N)$$

is obvious to conclude that

$$\text{If} \  f \in L^{1}(0,1) \ \text{then} \  \displaystyle\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \sin (\lambda x) \ dx = 0  \ (\lambda \in R)$$

I am not seeing how to show this...

Someone can give me a hint ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $$F(\lambda):=\int_0^1 f(x) \sin (\lambda x) \mathrm{d}x. $$ The sentence you have written merely proves that $F(\lambda) \to 0$ along the sequence $\lambda_n=n$. If you want to prove that the limit exists as $\lambda \to \infty$ continuously, you must show that for *any* sequence $(\lambda_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ tending to $\infty$, $F(\lambda_n) \to 0$ (This is the Heine definition of continuity). In short, the answer is no, it is not that obvious to generalize your statement.

However, there is a [more general statement of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma), from which the conclusion is immediate.